# Python 2.7.17 - PyAutoGUI says Pillow is not installed, but it is installed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I'm currently making an app that takes a screenshot and compares some stuff on it. It is currently, after a long while, I managed to get a different error than I was getting before, further ahead in the program (hooray for progress!)

I've posted the traceback, where it says that the Pillow package is required, but it has already been installed along with PyAutoGUI. I've installed previous versions, hoping it'd fix the problem. It hasn't...

I'm making it on Windows XP 32 bit (yes, I know, it has reached EOL over 5 years ago, but the target computer has WinXP.

Here's a list of all the packages I have installed:

```
Package     Version
----------- -------
MouseInfo   0.1.2
numpy       1.16.6
Pillow      6.0.0
pip         20.0.2
PyAutoGUI   0.9.48
PyGetWindow 0.0.8
PyMsgBox    1.0.7
pyperclip   1.7.0
PyRect      0.1.4
PyScreeze   0.1.26
PyTweening  1.0.3
setuptools  41.2.0
```

Can you guys help me out?

Code:

```
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import pyautogui
import datetime
import time

global LatestLine

# Square 1 Coordinates - Check if machine is working
x1=280
y1=55
h1=31
w1=33
# Square 2 Coordinates - Check if program is active
x2=157
y2=177
h2=38
w2=38

while True:
    #Get Screenshot
    imagem = pyautogui.screenshot()
    imagem.save(r'C:/Machine_Tracker/Imagem_Moving.png')

    print ("Screenshot taken")

    #Set image
    imagem = cv2.imread("C:/Machine_Tracker/Imagem_Moving.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    im = cv2.bitwise_not(imagem)

    now = datetime.datetime.now() 
    # Read square 1 - Check if machine is working
    print "Crop image to check if machine is working"
    crop_img = im[y1:y1+h1, x1:x1+w1]
    n_white_pix1 = np.sum(crop_img == 255)
    print('Number of white pixels:', n_white_pix1)
    #cv2.imshow("Machine Status: White Pixels: {0}".format(n_white_pix1), crop_img)
    cv2.imwrite("C:/Machine_Tracker/Machine_Status/MachineStatus.png", crop_img)

    # Read square 2 - Check if program is active
    print "Crop image to check if program is active"
    crop_img = im[y2:y2+h2, x2:x2+w2]
    n_white_pix2 = np.sum(crop_img == 255)
    print('Number of white pixels:', n_white_pix2)
    #cv2.imshow("Program Status: White Pixels: {0}".format(n_white_pix2), crop_img)
    cv2.imwrite("C:/Machine_Tracker/App_Status/AppStatus.png", crop_img)

    #Se Estiver na app
        # Se Estiver a trabalhar
            #Escreve "Working + DateTime"
        # Else
            #Escreve "Not Working + DateTime"
        #EndIf
    # Else
        #Escreve "Fora Da App + Datetime"
    #endif

    if n_white_pix2 == 608: #Esta na app
        if n_white_pix1 <= 1023: #Esta a trabalhar
            #Quando a maquina nao esta a trabalhar,
            #o bocado que vamos buscar tem 1023 pixeis brancos
            #Sempre que e menor que esse valor, a maquina esta a trabalhar
            #Write machine working log to file
            Log = open("C:/Machine_Tracker/StatusLog.txt", "w")
            LatestLine = "{0} - App is open and Machine is working\n".format(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            Log.write(LatestLine)
            Log.close()
            #print LatestLine
            print(LatestLine)
        else:
            #Write machine working log to file
            Log = open("C:/Machine_Tracker/StatusLog.txt", "w")
            LatestLine = "{0} - App is open but Machine is NOT working\n".format(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            Log.write(LatestLine)
            Log.close()
            print(LatestLine)
    else:
        #Write machine working log to file
        Log = open("C:/Machine_Tracker/StatusLog.txt", "w")
        LatestLine = "{0} - App is NOT open\n".format(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        Log.write(LatestLine)
        Log.close()
        print(LatestLine)

    time.sleep(20)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Check_for_Status.py", line 24, in <module>
    imagem = pyautogui.screenshot()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 134, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.
```

Comment: Please try to upgrade **Pillow** using- "pip install Pillow --upgrade". If the error still exists let me know

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try importing Pillow in your python code??? I am not sure, but try to include this at the top:

```
import Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running in Command Propmpt

```
import PIL
import pyautogui
pyautogui.screenshot()
```

Comment: can you add screenshot or formatted output that will be helpful